# TYPO3 9.5 Introduction package

Tags: typo3

How can I get the language selection from the footer into the header area - with introduction-package in TYPO3?

Comment: "How can I" asks for how to do it, "Does anyone know" however can be answered with yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

The introduction-package (technically a "TYPO3 distribution") uses the extension [bootstrap-package](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/bootstrap_package/) for the layout.

If you have not already you would want to define Fluid paths for overwriting certain templates: https://docs.typo3.org/p/bk2k/bootstrap-package/11.0/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#page-fluidtemplate.

This would add your path to the chain of Fluid directories with highest priority.

To move around the language menu you'll want to change where this partial in included (finding the partial is easy by searching for recognizable HTML-code like IDs):
`Partials/Page/Navigation/Language.html`

You can include it in your overwritten
`Partials/Page/Navigation/Main.html` like this:

```
<f:render partial="Navigation/Language" arguments="{_all}" />
```

The `Partials/Page/Navigation/Main.html` is just an example. You can put it where you want. But you have to make sure that the used variable `languagenavigation` is passed to your partial. That is done by the `arguments="..."`. For the example given this will work because it is itself included from the main `Layouts/Page/Default.html` and gets also `arguments="{_all}"`.

To learn where `languagenavigation` comes from have a look at `Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript`. You'll see it being filled by a `DataProcessor` inside a `10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE` block.

I hope that helps. Feel free to tell us how you fare :) And don't be shy to ask any further questions.